# Unpack matrices in numpy file and plot them

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need a code that reads a .npy file containing a set of arrays and creates a scatter plot using numpy and matplotlib. The first column need to be the x cordinates and the second column are the y cordinates

ex:
a = np.load("filename.npy")

```
 a

([[[19.3, 117.88],
[20.77, 118.99],
[18.92, 117.66],
[16.23, 115.67]],

[[16.335, 113.789],
 [17.876, 116.8],
 [22.76, 115.34],
 [23.33, 111.45]],

 [[22.56, 113.76],
  [21.6,  118.07],
  [18.3,  116.60],
  [21.739, 117.903]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply slice the "columns" (actually the third dimension) and pass it to [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). Matplotlib will flatten the inputs internally.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(a[:, :, 0], a[:, :, 1])
```

Hacky alternative:

```
plt.scatter(*a.reshape(-1, 2).T)
```

Output:

[image]